# Deploy all dependencies from pom.xml to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I am a newbie to JFrog.  As part of security testing, I was told to use JFrog to download all the jar instead of maven repository. Is it possible to auto deploy all dependencies from pom.xml to JFrog artifacts instead of uploading each jar to JFrog artifact? So that later I can point my pom repository to this JFrog atifactory where the necessary dependencies are already deployed in JFrog?

Edit:
The bottom line is, no dependencies should be downloaded from internet/maven. It should be downloaded via JFrog so that I can have control over versions being used in projects. For instance,there should be only one spring framework version for all the projects. All the upload of jars should be done manually to the JFrog Repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your dependencies are probably from external Maven repositories.

You just add these Maven repositories to the Artifactory and then build. No need to upload anything.

If you have external dependencies that do *not* come from a Maven repository, you need to upload them manually. But usually, the number will be small.

Comment: As part of security testing, my company need to download all the dependencies/jar from the JFrog artifactory instead of downloading from internet during maven build. I dont have much 3rd party  dependencies. Everything is available from maven.

Comment: Then I would have a separate repository in Artifactory that you use for builds. Then you can copy downloaded artifacts from the other (external) repositories to the one you use for internal builds. Also note that JFrog offers a tool named Xray for security scanning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with artifactory the dependency should be already there. I am using artifactory as main repository and artifactory is caching. This work like your local repository.

If you are working in a company and do you have configured this artifactory, then you will get the dependencies throug this artifactory and therefore there is not need to upload 3rd parties.

If you have added 3rd libraries manually to your local repository by mvn install.
(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) you need also to upload them to artifactory. e.g. by http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

An automatic way I don't know for this.

Do you want to deploy to another artifactory than your next company repo?

Comment: You wrote that you have to download it from JFrog Artifactory. You should not download it manually. (Only if the Artifactory repository does not belong to your company.) Configure your company Artifactory as your main repository. Then your local maven instance will download it automaticaly from threre and you don't need to upload something anymore.